# Start a workflow every first day of the month

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

Is it possible to start a workflow automatically the first day of every month?
Edit:
In principle I think this has to be programmatically although if it can be achieved using an out of the box features it'd be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can start workflow using 2 diffrent approch as below.

1. Create one timer job which will run on every first of the month & kickoff the workflow programatically.
2. Create custom workflow which will run when item added but wait until 1st date of the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a workflow for the list you are monitoring and set the action to wait until the 1st day of the month before doing the rest of the actions.